# Trouble with ajax/jsp session variables

Tags: ajax, jsp

The below was working yesterday but is not today.  I can't figure out if I accidentally deleted something or changed something in my IDE.  Really appreciate an extra set of eyes.  Thank you.

NewFile.jsp

```
<%@ page session="true"%>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>
function setvar(this2) {
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "NewFile1.jsp",
          data: {myID:this2},
          dataType: "text",
          success: function () 
            {
              document.getElementById("myvar").value=${sessionScope.myID};
            }         
        });}
</script>

<input type="button" name="my444ID" id="444" value="444" onclick="setvar(this.id);">
<input type="button" name="my555ID" id="555" value="555" onclick="setvar(this.id);">
<p><input type="text" name="myvar" id="myvar" value=""></p>
```

NewFile1.jsp

```
<%
HttpSession ses = request.getSession();
ses.setAttribute("myID", request.getParameter("myID"));
%>
```

Comment: are you seeing any error inside browser console ?

Comment: If you are referring to the console in Eclipse that runs when I initiate the Tomcat server - no, there are no errors written there.

Comment: No your browsers console tab .  Click `Control + Shift + C` then go in console tab there you will find errors if there are any .

Comment: Got it.  Switched to external browser.  Got three errors:

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: NewFile.jsp:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: setvar is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (NewFile.jsp:17)

Comment: first put that whole script tag after your `<p><input type="text" name="myvar" id="myvar" value..` . Then , put this `${sessionScope.myID}` in `""` i.e : `"${sessionScope.myID}";`

Comment: Thank you!  It's now populating the box though oddly it says "555" whichever button I choose.  Any thoughts on that?  Do I need to clear the session variable first or something?

Comment: is `this2` giving you correct values ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230162/discussion-between-swati-and-warrenjb).